# How to parse cookie header in a Socket.io Autherization?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, express, socket.io

I want to read the session/cookie data before the user connect to a websocket.

My websocket is implemented using Socket.io and express framework.

Here is what I have done

```
const env = require('./config');
const sess = require('./sessions');
const app = require('express')();
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const session = require('express-session');
const RedisStore = require("connect-redis")(session);
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const connect = require('connect');
const server = https.createServer(
    {
        key: fs.readFileSync('certs/key.pem'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('certs/cert.pem')
    }, function (req, res){
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type');
    }
).listen(env.socket.port, env.socket.host, function () {
    console.log('\033[2J');
    console.log('Websocket is running at https://%s:%s', server.address().address, server.address().port);
});

const io = require('socket.io')(server);

const sessionMiddleware = session({
    store: new RedisStore({
        host: env.redis.host,
        port: env.redis.port
    }),
    secret: env.session.secret,
    name: env.session.name,
    rolling: false,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
});

var clients = {};

io.use(function(socket, next) {
    sessionMiddleware(socket.request, socket.request.res, next);
});
var myCookieParser = cookieParser(env.session.secret);

app.use( myCookieParser ) ;
app.use( sessionMiddleware );

io.set('authorization', function (handshakeData, accept) {

    onsole.log(handshakeData.headers.cookie);

    if (handshakeData.headers.cookie) {

        var cookies = myCookieParser(handshakeData.headers.cookie);
        console.log(cookies);
        return ;

        handshakeData.sessionID = connect.utils.parseSignedCookie(cookies['connect.sid'], env.session.secret);

    if (cookies['connect.sid'] == handshakeData.sessionID) {
        return accept('Cookie is invalid.', false);
    }

  } else {
        return accept('No cookie transmitted.', false);
  } 

  accept(null, true);
});


io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    var origin = socket.request.headers.origin || '';
    var myIP = socket.request.socket.remoteAddress || '';
    var socketId = socket.id;
    var session_id = '';
    var authorized = false;
    var req = socket.request;

    //console.log(socket.request);
    console.log('SessionID: ' + socket.request.sessionID)

    if (!originIsAllowed(origin)) {
        // Make sure we only accept requests from an allowed origin
        socket.destroy();
        console.log((new Date()) + ' Connection from origin ' + origin + ' rejected.');
        return false;
    }

    if(req.sessionID){
        session_id = req.sessionID;
    }

    if(req.session.authorized){
        authorized = req.session.authorized;
    }

    socket.on('chat', function(msg){
        //only autherized users can chat
        if( session.authorized ){
            console.log('Chat Message: ' + msg);
            socket.emit('chat', { message: msg });
        }

    });


    socket.on('disconnect', function(msg){
        console.log('Closing sessionID: ' + session_id);
        var userCons = clients[session_id] || [];

        var index = userCons.indexOf(socketId);

        if(index > -1){
            userCons.splice(index, 1);
            console.log('Removed Disconnect Message: ' + msg);
        } else {
            console.log('Disconnect Message: ' + msg);
        }

    }); 

    socket.on('error', function(msg){
        console.log('Error Message: ' + msg);
    }); 

});


function originIsAllowed(origin) {
    // put logic here to detect whether the specified origin is allowed.
        var allowed = env.session.allowedOrigins || []

        if(allowed.indexOf(origin) >= 0){
            return true;
        }

    return false;
}
```

When I start the server I get all kids of error

```
Websocket is running at https://10.0.4.18:8020
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\cookie-parser\index.js:26
    var cookies = req.headers.cookie;
                             ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'cookie' of undefined
    at cookieParser (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\cookie-parser\index.js
:26:30)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\socket.js:79:17
    at Array.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\socket.io\lib\ind
ex.js:118:7)
    at run (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\socket.io\lib\namespace.js:114:
11)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\socket.io\lib\namespace.js:122:7
    at session (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\express-session\index.js:39
8:7)
```

The server is complaining about this line

```
var cookies = myCookieParser(handshakeData.headers.cookie);
```

How can I correctly parse the cookies?

**Edited**

after changing the problem like to this

```
var cookies = myCookieParser(handshakeData);
```

I get this error

```
Websocket is running at https://10.0.4.18:8020
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\cookie-parser\index.js:48
    next();
    ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at cookieParser (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\cookie-parser\index.js
:48:5)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\socket.js:61:17
    at Array.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\socket.io\lib\ind
ex.js:118:7)
    at run (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\socket.io\lib\namespace.js:114:
11)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\socket.io\lib\namespace.js:122:7
    at session (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\express-session\index.js:39
8:7)
    at Array.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\socket.js:40:5)
    at run (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\socket.io\lib\namespace.js:114:
11)
    at Namespace.run (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\socket.io\lib\namespa
ce.js:126:3)
    at Namespace.add (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\socket.io\lib\namespa
ce.js:155:8)
```

Comment: The error references a completely different line `var cookies = req.headers.cookie;`, I think you need to look in a different place.

Comment: @YuriZarubin when comment that line and return after it I do not get that error

Comment: Oh right, nvm. Yeah the reason its complaining is because its expecting a `request` object, not the actual cookie. So its trying to parse the actual cookie.

Comment: @YuriZarubin when I do this `myCookieParser(handshakeData.headers)` I get an error too

Comment: Right, because that's not the request object either. How about `myCookieParser(handshakeData)`

Comment: I get a different error I will post it in my question now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89863/discussion-between-mike-a-and-yuri-zarubin).